# Using jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut transition where only one element is visible at a time

Tags: jquery, css, animation, fadeout

I've tried:

```
$("#el1").fadeOut();
$("#el2").fadeIn();
```

but I can't have two elements on the screen at the same time, the first one must be completely hidden before the second one can fade in, so this doesn't work.

I've also tried:

```
$("#el1").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#el2").fadeIn();
});
```

which seems to work ok but the problem is that when the states (this animation is from a link click) are toggled quickly while animating, you can get a case where both end up 
visible.

I've also tried `.stop()` but it didn't seem to help either.

How can I get the behaviour I need with jQuery, so that only the last clicked link is visible, not any of the others, and only one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the document of jquery on the stop() method: http://api.jquery.com/stop/ .
You can give the stop-method some parameters to work with: stop([clearqueu],[jump_to_end]);
You probably need something like this:

```
$("#el1").stop(false, true).fadeOut(function() {
    $("#el2").stop(false, true).fadeIn();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just tried that but the problem of being able to get 'stuck' out of sync remains when clicking during animation.